# Alexa is picking only US cities for city intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing an app for the weather where the user has to respond with the city name when alexa ask for. My city intent read like this

```
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "cityName",
      "type": "AMAZON.US_CITY"
    }
  ],
  "intent": "cityIntent"
}
```

When user says only city name like San Francisco, Chicago or New York, it processed but if user is giving another city name like Mumbai, London, Manchester, it won't pick it up and directly go for stop intent. But if I am saying Change My City To Mumbai, then it is processing the city.

And Changed the AMAZON.US_CITY to AMAZON.GB_CITY too but it didn't work for me.

Comment: AMAZON.literal is your best bet... https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/45790/query-location-data-in-user-intent.html

Comment: But the question itself is saying that they have deprecated LITERALS

Comment: LITERALS are not deprecated.. read link https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution

Comment: Why I am able to get the city when I am saying change my city to Mumbai, but not getting when I am saying only Mumbai. It's Not like AMAZON.US_CITY is not allowing Mumbai or any other city but it is not allowing it like it is allowing US city.

Comment: AMAZON.literal is only available in en-US and if you change your locale to US English then your skill won't be available in Amazon Indian skill store. The best bet would be to extend inbuilt alexa slots https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/Tx3Q9SLKOW69DJ0/new-ask-features-extensible-built-in-types

Comment: still, my app is available for all the country. Even if I consider only India, can you imagine how many cities do I have to include in slot type?